# Python - Each WebSocket connection as a separate process

Tags: python, websocket, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Suppose if the system has 4 CPU's, I need to run eight workers on It. On starting the server, I want to initialize the eight workers. I want to forward the data to available workers on the new WebSocket connection and change that worker's status to occupied. If all of the workers are occupied, then the server should not accept any new connections.

I don't want to exchange data between the processes. But I need to send data to the correct Process when new data is received in the WebSocket. Whenever the WebSocket connection drops, then I need to change the status of the worker to available.

```
# Something like this, 
# FYI : The following is not a python code, just a representation of the requirement


process_manager = ProcessManager()

WebSocket 

    onNewConnection:
        available_process = process_manager.get_available_process()
        if available_process:
            available_process.set_state(state.Occupied)
        else:
            ws.write("Server is on full load")

        

    onNewMessage(_data):
        available_process.sendData(_data)

    OnSocketClose:
        available_process.set_state(state.Available)
    



__main__
    process_pool = ProcessPool (8)
    for loop 0 to 7 as i
        process_manager.put(i,Process)
    #-- start all process
    #-- join all process
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need multiprocessing to run your concurrent requests rather than multithreading and you are on a platform that supports the OS `fork` call, then you might want to investigate the high-level `socketserver.TCPServer` class used in conjunction with the `socketserver.ForkingMixIn` class. Although, this will fork a new process for each new incoming request. On any platform, if threading will suffice, you can use the `socketserver.ThreadingMixIn` class. With the latter it should be a fairly simple matter to keep a count of started active requests that get incremented when your request handler gets called and decremented when it completes (under a control of a `threading.Lock`). For the former case (multiprocessing), this counter would have to be a shared memory value, such as created with `multiprocessing.Value('h', lock=multiprocessing.Lock())`.

But if you want to use a multiprocessing pool, then perhaps the following might suit your requirements. I have created a special multiprocessing pool class that essentially only supports the `apply_async` method, which allows you to submit new, non-blocking tasks but will keep track of how many tasks are running + waiting to run (in your case there will be 0 tasks waiting to run). So you simply have to check the current task count before submitting the request to the pool:

```py
import multiprocessing
import threading

class MyPool:
    """
    Process pool class that only supports the following methods:
    apply_async
    close
    join
    terminate
    task_count
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._task_count = 0
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        self._pool = multiprocessing.Pool(*args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        self._pool.__enter__()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return self._pool.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

    def close(self):
        return self._pool.close()

    def join(self):
        return self._pool.join()

    def terminate(self):
        return self._pool.terminate()

    def task_count(self):
        """
        return number of tasks running or queued up to run
        """
        return self._task_count

    def _decrement_task_count(self, result, callback=None):
        with self._lock:
            self._task_count -= 1
        if callback:
            callback(result)

    def apply_async(self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None, error_callback=None):
        with self._lock:
            self._task_count += 1
        callback_fn = self._decrement_task_count if callback is None else lambda result: self._decrement_task_count(result, callback=callback)
        error_callback_fn = self._decrement_task_count if error_callback is None else lambda result: self._decrement_task_count(result, callback=callback)
        return self._pool.apply_async(func, args, kwds, callback=callback_fn, error_callback=error_callback_fn)

def handle_request(client_socket):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import socket

    SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'
    SERVER_PORT = 4000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
    s.listen(5)
    with MyPool(8) as pool:
        while True:
            client_socket, address = s.accept()
            if pool.task_count() < 8:
                # We can run this
                pool.apply_async(handle_request, args=(client_socket,))
            else:
                client_socket.send(b'Server is on full load')
        """
        # We will never arrive here as the code currently stands:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        """
```